Python Dash - Line chart with dropdown menu for filtering by multiple columns
I'm trying to build a line chart, showing tonnage over time, with a dropdown menu based on multiple columns, Lists 1 to 3, using Dash.
The line chart will show 7 lines, Tonnage with List 1 "Y" up to Tonnage with List 3 "N", with the dropdown menu to toggle for specific lines only, and the option to show all.
However, I can't seem to include all 7 selection options into the dropdown menu, am I missing something?
The raw data and Python dataframe loaded is as:

The code I applied is as:
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='category-filter',
        options=[
            {'label': 'All', 'value': 'All'}] + [{'label': category, 'value': category} for category in df['LIST 1'].unique()],
        value='All',  
        style={'width': '50%'}
    ),
    
    
    dcc.Graph(id='line-chart')
])

@app.callback(
    dash.Output('line-chart', 'figure'),
    [dash.Input('category-filter', 'value')]
)
def update_chart(selected_category):
    filtered_df = df if selected_category == 'All' else df[df['LIST 1'] == selected_category]
    
    
    figure = {
        'data': [
            go.Scatter(
                x=filtered_df['DATE'],
                y=filtered_df['TONNAGE'],
                mode='lines+markers',
                name=selected_category if selected_category != 'All' else 'All Categories'
            )
        ],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title='Line Chart with Dropdown Filter',
            xaxis={'title': 'Date'},
            yaxis={'title': 'Tonnage'}
        )
    }
    return figure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

Many thanks!

However, I can't seem to include all 7 selection options into the dropdown menu
    options=[{'label': 'All', 'value': 'All'}] + 
        [{'label': category, 'value': category} for category in df['LIST 1'].unique()]

This code only adds filtering by the values from column "LIST 1". You can see that other columns are not even mentioned.
If you also want filters for "LIST 2" and "LIST 3" you should add another two dcc.Dropdown elements to your application layout, add their id's to input and change the function's logic to filter the dataframe depending on all the three dropdowns.
You can also craft 7 options for a single dropdown list and change the update_chart function accordingly, but that would look sloopy and users would not be able to filter by two or three columns at a time.
    options=[{'label': 'All', 'value': 'All'}] + 
        [{'label': "list_1_" + category, 'value': "list_1_" + category} for category in df['LIST 1'].unique()] + 
        [{'label': "list_2_" + category, 'value': "list_2_" + category} for category in df['LIST 2'].unique()] + 
        [{'label': "list_3_" + category, 'value': "list_3_" + category} for category in df['LIST 3'].unique()]

In this case you will also have to replace the filtering in the update_chart function to something like:
if selected_category == 'All':
   filtered_df = df
elif 'list_1' in selected_category:
   filtered_df = df[df['LIST 1'] == selected_category[-1]]
elif 'list_2' in selected_category:
   filtered_df = df[df['LIST 2'] == selected_category[-1]]
else:
   filtered_df = df[df['LIST 3'] == selected_category[-1]]

